# Bash error while compiling boost with cmake

Tags: bash, boost, cmake

I'm trying to compile boost(as part of another library installation) but it reports to me that my gcc is broken.

when I run cmake I get

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (MESSAGE):
  The C compiler "/usr/bin/gcc" is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: /home/lecopivo/code/bempp-inst/bempp/build/contrib/boost/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec3895803733/fast"

  /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3895803733.dir/build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3895803733.dir/build

  make[1]: Entering directory
  `/home/lecopivo/code/bempp-inst/bempp/build/contrib/boost/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


  /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report
  /home/lecopivo/code/bempp-inst/bempp/build/contrib/boost/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles
  1

  Building C object
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3895803733.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

  /usr/bin/gcc -m64 -O3 -march=native (Default on Linux) -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3895803733.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c
  /home/lecopivo/code/bempp-inst/bempp/build/contrib/boost/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c


  /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

  make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3895803733.dir/testCCompiler.c.o]
  Error 2

  make[1]: Leaving directory
  `/home/lecopivo/code/bempp-inst/bempp/build/contrib/boost/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


  make: *** [cmTryCompileExec3895803733/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:28 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I really do not know what might be wrong. When I make my own cmake project in C I have no problems compiling it.

Comment: Worth saying that `Boost.CMake` is not usual way building boost. Usually we use `Boost.Build` system. See [www.boost.org: Getting Started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html). Also, your compiler is [a bit outdated.](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/releases.html) None of this are issues, but could make your life more difficult. As for CMake, you clearly have problems with this line: `/usr/bin/gcc -m64 -O3 -march=native (Default on Linux) ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is not from `gcc` but from `/bin/sh`, there is no sign that the problem is actually with gcc itself.

```
/usr/bin/gcc -m64 -O3 -march=native (Default on Linux) -o
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3895803733.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c
/home/lecopivo/code/bempp-inst/bempp/build/contrib/boost/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c


/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Is this value `(Default on Linux)` something that you have entered somewhere?

Comment: I'm so blind :D Fixed and works. I wondered why there was an error with `sh`.

Comment: I'm thinking about deleting the question. Because it would be only misleading and unhelpful for future googlers. Are you okay with it? I guess you wont get your 15 points if I delete it.

Comment: You do as you feel is best. I suppose the takeaway from the question as it currently stands is to read the log carefully to see what actually happened as opposed to taking the initial "Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- broken" message at face value.